# Nested calling vs. Calling step by step

Tags: c++, function, time-complexity

Is it better, from complexity eye of view, to call a function and return its value to another function

```
a = foo();
bar (a);
```

Or to make a nested call?

```
bar(foo());
```

Indeed, I am making this millions of times.

If it depends on something else, please mention it.

Comment: perhaps you should benchmark.... In many instances, I suspect the compiler will optimise appropriately.

Comment: Depends entirely on the implementation of the move/copy-assignment and move/copy-construction semantics of the return type of `foo()`. In particular, the second form will copy the value in `a`, in particular the `bar(a)` call. This might be expensive. A better example is `a = foo(); bar(std::move(a));`.

Comment: From a complexity standpoint, it makes no difference, however, readability and debugging may become hampered with the latter approach.

Comment: @MitchWheat am sending high rates of data on loopback. So, each time I run the application I get completely different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go for clarity - the compiler should optimize the temporary away. But if it's critical, benchmark and look at the assembly code.

Comment: you are right, maybe the assembly code would help me.